# Center multiple words on a path to different segments in a circle using Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, text, alignment, text-on-path

**Problem:**

Centering multiple words on a path in relation to the segment that each word belongs to. I wish to do this in Illustrator.

**Example (what is done so far):**

I created a circle and divided it into 12 segments and gave each segment a color. Then I created another circle outside to give each color a label.

[image]
**Desired output:**

To center the word for each color right above the color it belongs to (see yellow in the example).

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry about that, it has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *Object > Transform > Rotate* on the text on the path, rotate it 30 degrees, press "Copy" to make the first copy.  Press <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat until you have all the text.

Edit the text with the text tool.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want each item equidistant, you can use tabs.

Merely select the type and choose `Window > Type > Tabs` from the menu. And set tabs to all be the same distance. And, of course, have a tab in the text between each item.

[image]

This keeps all the type on a path on the same circle, making editing easier at times.

---

You can also use the **Paragraph Panel** and set the type to **Force Justify** with simply a space between each word. This will evenly distribute the text on the path except between the first and last item.

[image]

To fix the first/last item issue, throw in a random character as the last item. Set the cursor right before it and change the kerning to compensate for the character. Then set the character's color to `none`.

[image]